# insert a custom style inside two different theme

Tags: android, xml, android-theme

I want to add a custom style that is for example purple in one theme and red in one other theme.

```
<style name="subtitle_layout" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/purple</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">40sp</item>
</style>

<style name="subtitle_layout2" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">80sp</item>
</style>
```

---

```
<style name="Theme1" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="@style/subtitle_layout">@style/subtitle_layout</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme2" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="@style/subtitle_layout">@style/subtitle_layout2</item>
</style>
```

The change of theme works because i see the change of text color, but instead of android:textColor i would like to put a style instead. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to inherit existing styles to your theme, am I right? You can just set the style as your parent theme:

```
<style name="Theme1" parent="@style/subtitle_layout">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: No theme is a global theme of all my app.